# Implementation of String.prototype.startsWith in ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, object, clojurescript

I need to convert this Javascript code into ClojureScript. I'm having some trouble with the `this` keyword.

Here's my JS:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
    position = position || 0;
    return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
  };
}
```

I'm getting a `Object doesn't support property or method 'startsWith'` error with the Google Closure compiler in advanced mode so I need to add this code. (IE 11)

Comment: What kind of trouble? What have you tried?

Comment: What's the issue with `this`? The usage looks correct.

Comment: But more importantly: You should use an actual polyfill, not just a function that does something similar to the specification. [Here is better implementation](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.startsWith) or at least take the one from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ClojureScript code:

```
(when (not (.. js/String -prototype -startsWith))
  (set!
    (.. js/String -prototype -startsWith)
    (fn [searchString position]
      (set! position (or position 0))
      (= (this-as this (.indexOf this) searchString position) position))))
```

Answer (score 5):

ClojureScript already has `clojure.string/starts-with?`:

```
$ clj -Sdeps '{:deps {org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "RELEASE"}}}' -m cljs.main -re node
ClojureScript 1.10.520
cljs.user=> (require '[clojure.string :as str])
nil
cljs.user=> (str/starts-with? "foobar" "foo")
true
```

[re-find](https://re-find.it/?args=%22foobar%22%20%22foo%22&ret=true) can also help you find it.

Comment: I'm having Object doesn't support property or method 'startsWith' error after Google Closure compiler in advance mode.

Comment: Which version of CLJS are you using? Can you post a minimal repro in a gist?

Comment: "1.10.520" but I'm getting this error on IE 11 only.